# Avoid overwriting files using regex

Tags: java, regex, filenames

I have a class that replaces illegal characters that strings might contain to allow using them as filenames. The problem is that it replaces any illegal character with "_", which is fine as long as the string does not entirely consist of illegal characters.
For example `cleanFilename(">>>")` will return the same string `cleanFilename("***")` returns. So storing `"***"` in a file after storing `">>>"`, would replace the first file.

```
public class StringCleaner {

    public static String cleanFilename(String dirtyString) {
        return dirtyString.replaceAll("[:\\/*?|<> ]", "_");
    }

    public static String cleanDirectory(String dirtyDirectory) {
        return dirtyDirectory.replaceAll("[:\\*?|<> ]", "_");
    }
}
```

What can i change in order to avoid this problem?
Sorry for the awkward title I could not find a better one.

**Update:** I want it to create readable filenames so that identification through reading the filename only will be possible.

*Thanks*
*Selim*

Comment: You'll just want to test to see if the new directory/filename is already used. If so then maybe append an integer and then retest, incrementing the appended integer in each test until a unique directory/filename is generated. My Java isn't good enough to give you the code for it but I'm sure someone here will.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR that would be fine for storing but that would cause trouble when im loading the file. When i try to load ">>>" it won't know wether it is ___ or ___1 or ___2 etc.

Comment: how about hash the filename with md5. if file exists, add timestamp or similar then hash, if you don't mind unreadable filenames. Or append (a short) timestamp when file was uploaded to filename.

Comment: @gwillie I should have mentioned in the question that i want the user to be able to recognize the file created so they can remove/edit it easily. I'll update my question if possible.

Comment: if your users are using invaild characters in filenames, maybe get the user to change it, giving then some possible suggestions along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are looking for a reversible and repeatable mechanism for replacing funny characters in file names. A typical way to do this is to create an escape sequence. For example, consider the following:

Pick a single character to use as an escape sequence. This character must be a legal character in a file name, but not commonly used, and we will use it as an escape sequence.

Let's chose the `+` character. Then, we replace all illegal characters with a sequence of characters that uniquely identfy the replaced character.

For example, replacing the space (character 32) in the file "this has a space" would give the result "this+32+has+32+a+32+space" ....

```
public class StringCleaner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringCleaner sc = new StringCleaner();
        System.out.println(sc.cleanFilename("this has a space"));
        System.out.println(sc.cleanFilename("this has a plus +"));
        System.out.println(sc.cleanFilename("this is full :\\/*?|<> + of stuff"));
    }

    private static final Pattern illegalfilechars = Pattern.compile("[:\\/*?|<> +]");
    private static final Pattern illegaldirchars = Pattern.compile("[:\\*?|<> +]");

    private static final String replaceall(Pattern pattern, String dirtyString) {
        Matcher mat = pattern.matcher(dirtyString);
        if (!mat.find()) {
            return dirtyString;
        }
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        do {
            mat.appendReplacement(sb, "+" + (int)mat.group(0).charAt(0) + "+");
        } while (mat.find());
        mat.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String cleanFilename(String dirtyString) {
        return replaceall(illegalfilechars, dirtyString);
    }

    public static String cleanDirectory(String dirtyDirectory) {
        return replaceall(illegaldirchars, dirtyDirectory);
    }
}
```

When I run the code I get the results:

```
this+32+has+32+a+32+space
this+32+has+32+a+32+plus+32++43+
this+32+is+32+full+32++58+\+47++42++63++124++60++62++32++43++32+of+32+stuff
```

which also indicates that the pattern is wrong for the character '\'

Comment: For the character '\' I used [link](http://regexpal.com/) and it seemed to work there. The original regex was "[:\\\\/*?|<> ]" i modified it as I thought that 2 backslashes would also do the job.
I think that will do the job, thank you very much!